# SwiftUI Text doesn't localise when inside ForEach

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui, localization

When my `Text` gets it's string from an array, it doesn't localise, but when I hard-code it in, it does:

#### Localizable.strings

```
"greeting1" = "Hello there";
"greeting2" = "Howdy";
```

*(Localised into English)*

#### My View

```
var localisedStrings = ["greeting1", "greeting2"]

struct Message: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(localisedStrings, id: \.self) { string in
            Text(string)
        }
    }
}
```

The text will just write the key, like
"**greeting1**", rather than "**Hello there**"

Is there a way to force the `Text` object to use a localised string? Or is it changing somehow because it's getting it's content from a `ForEach` loop?

#### My View (hard coded)

```
//var localisedStrings = ["greeting1", "greeting2"]

struct Message: View {
    var body: some View {
        //ForEach(localisedStrings, id: \.self) { string in
            Text("greeting1")
        //}
    }
}
```

This works just fine, and results in the text displaying "**Hello there**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when you hardcode the string in, because you are using this [initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:tablename:bundle:comment:)), which takes a `LocalizedStringKey`.

`LocalizedStringKey` is `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, but the word `string` in `Text(string)` is not a "string literal", so it calls [this initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:)-9d1g4) instead, and is not localised. You can initialise an instance of `LocalizedStringKey` directly, in order to localise it:

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because here you are using plain `String` Swift type

```swift
var localisedStrings = ["greeting1", "greeting2"]
```

and here you are using SwiftUI own [`LocalizedStringKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/localizedstringkey) type

```swift
Text("greeting1")
```

To fix your issue map your `string` to `LocalizedStringKey`

```swift
struct Message: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(localisedStrings, id: \.self) { string in
            Text(LocalizedStringKey(string))
        }
    }
}
```

[`Text.init(_:tableName:bundle:comment:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:tablename:bundle:comment:))

Please follow the linked documentation to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above did not work for me, this is the one that did:

```
    ForEach(viewModel.content) { content in
        Text(LocalizedStringKey(stringLiteral: "content_\(content.name)"))
    }
```

I had to add "stringLiteral", if I passed the string directly into LocalizedStringKey it wouldn't recognize the keys on the localized files.